# Problem in Form Show

Tags: c#

i wrote this code but when i run it the debugger prompt me "DragDrop registration did not succeed." in FormAdver.show(); line , how can i fix it ?

```
    public void ResiveFunc(string FuncResive)
    {


        string FuncName = "";
        string FuncValue = "";
        for (int i = 0; i <= 2; i++)
        {
            FuncName += FuncResive[i];
        }
        for (int j = 4; j <= FuncResive.Length - 1; j++)
        {
            FuncValue += FuncResive[j];
        }
        MessageBox.Show(FuncName);
        MessageBox.Show(FuncValue);
        if (FuncName == "TAB")
        {
            Form1 mainForm = new Form1();
            frmAddver formAddver = new frmAddver();
            formAddver.Show();
            mainForm.AdverFilter(FuncValue);

        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem with multi threaded / invocation:(](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4769915/problem-with-multi-threaded-invocation)

Comment: This is just a re-hash of your previous question, I could repeat my questions about mainForm etc but you would just ignore them again.

Comment: Small improvement: consider to pass object instead of string: 
`class Func { public string Name { get;set; } public string Value { get; set; } public static Func FromString(string funcReceive) { parse_string_as_you_do_it_now } }` and pass it to your method `public void ReceiveFunc(Func func)`

Answer (score 0):

You have two options

1. Make sure `AllowDrop` is `false` on the controls in FormAdver
2. Make sure the the Apartment State is set to STA. Either by `Thread.CurrentThread.ApartmentState = ApartmentState.STA` or using the `[STAThread]` attribute.